# How do I make gprename to work in Xenial?

Tags: gprename

The icon in HUD won't work. When Launched from terminal I get "Path doesn't exist!". Please help

When I run `gprename .` I get `Permission denied for this folder!`

Comment: The question is simple what folder is `.` (where you started `gprename`)? Try `gprename ~`. On my clean system even `gprename /` does not produce error messages.

Comment: Thank you N0rbert! I think you found the bug: the current dir was `.foo`. And running `gprename .` from any regular (i.e. not a hidden one) subdir of a hidden folder triggers this error message, although `gprename regularDir/.hiddenDir` works OK. Actually, `gprename` doesn't like current folder is hidden, whatever the target parameter is.